# View height constraints are not set correctly as I scroll UICollectionView up and down

Tags: ios, xamarin, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to decide view heights based on a model property, but as `UICollectionView` is scrolled up and down, incorrect heights are assigned to visible cells. It seems that setting a `HeightAnchor` in `GetCell` (i.e. `cellForItemAtIndexPath`) does not work. How can I make this work?

```
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UIKit;

namespace App2
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        private UICollectionView _collectionView;

        public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            InitializeCollectionView();
        }

        private void InitializeCollectionView()
        {
            _collectionView = new UICollectionView(View.Frame, new UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(GetSection()))
            {
                DataSource = new CustomUICollectionViewDataSource(),
                TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            };

            _collectionView.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(CustomUICollectionViewCell), "CustomUICollectionViewCell");

            View.AddSubview(_collectionView);

            NSLayoutConstraint.ActivateConstraints(new[]
            {
                _collectionView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.TopAnchor),
                _collectionView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.BottomAnchor),
                _collectionView.LeftAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.LeftAnchor),
                _collectionView.RightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.RightAnchor)
            });
        }

        private static NSCollectionLayoutSection GetSection()
        {
            var size = NSCollectionLayoutSize.Create(NSCollectionLayoutDimension.CreateFractionalWidth(1), NSCollectionLayoutDimension.CreateEstimated(50));
            var item = NSCollectionLayoutItem.Create(size);
            var group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.CreateHorizontal(layoutSize: size, subitem: item, count: 1);
            var section = NSCollectionLayoutSection.Create(group);

            section.InterGroupSpacing = 5;

            return section;
        }
    }

    public class CustomUICollectionViewDataSource : UICollectionViewDataSource
    {
        private readonly List<Model> _models = new List<Model>
        {
            new Model {Height = 250},
            new Model {Height = 100},
            new Model {Height = 300},
            new Model {Height = 400},
            new Model {Height = 500},
            new Model {Height = 50},
            new Model {Height = 230},
            new Model {Height = 100},
            new Model {Height = 600},
            new Model {Height = 310},
            new Model {Height = 150},
            new Model {Height = 220}
        };

        public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var model = _models[(int)indexPath.Item];

            var cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("CustomUICollectionViewCell", indexPath) as CustomUICollectionViewCell;

            cell.UpdateHeight(model.Height);

            return cell;
        }

        public override nint GetItemsCount(UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
        {
            return _models.Count;
        }
    }

    public sealed class CustomUICollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
    {
        private readonly UIView _uiView;

        [Export("initWithFrame:")]
        public CustomUICollectionViewCell(CGRect frame) : base(frame)
        {
            _uiView = new UIView
            {
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Brown,
                TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            };

            ContentView.AddSubview(_uiView);

            NSLayoutConstraint.ActivateConstraints(new[]
            {
                _uiView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(ContentView.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.TopAnchor),
                _uiView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(ContentView.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.BottomAnchor),
                _uiView.LeftAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(ContentView.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.LeftAnchor),
                _uiView.RightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(ContentView.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.RightAnchor)
            });
        }

        public void UpdateHeight(int height)
        {
            _uiView.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(height).Active = true;
        }
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public int Height { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fix for this as recommended by [Xamarin support](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/172885/view-height-constraints-are-not-set-correctly-as-i-scroll-uicollectionview-up-and-down):

```
NSLayoutConstraint heightConstraint;
public void UpdateHeight(int height)
{
    if (heightConstraint == null)
    {
        heightConstraint = _uiView.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(height);
        heightConstraint.Active = true;
    }
    else
    {
        heightConstraint.Constant = height;
    }
}
```

Comment: `sizeForItemAt`  only works for `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, so it definitely won't work for `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this, the print message should prompt you to repeat the constraint.

You set the constraints of `left, right, bottom, top`, and added a `height` constraint when updating. The first four constraints have already determined the final height, the new height here will not work, and a warning message will be printed.

If you really want to update the height, you should set the `left, right, top, height` constraints from the beginning, and save the `height` constraint, which is used when updating.

```swift
var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

heightConstraint = _uiView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)//Defaults
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

(_uiView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:ContentView.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor))!,                
(_uiView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo:ContentView.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor))!
(_uiView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo:ContentView.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor))!,
(heightConstraint)!
]);
```

```swift
public void UpdateHeight(int height){
    heightConstraint?.isActive = false
    heightConstraint = _uiView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height)
    heightConstraint?.isActive = true
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this suggestion did not work. I removed the bottom anchor and created a class member for the height constraint. I updated it in `UpdateHeight` as you suggested. I can't see any `InterGroupSpacing` and the entire screen looks brown.

Comment: Before the update, the visible cells are rendered fine the first time the collection view is displayed. Heights are out of whack as I scroll.

Comment: The reason for this is that the height of `item` is fixed, and you can dynamically change the height of the internal view, which is likely to go beyond. Maybe you should consider setting the height of the `item` dynamically instead of changing the height of the internal view.

Comment: By `item`, do you mean `ContentView`? I removed `_uiView` from being its subview and set the height constraint directly on `ContentView`. Nothing.

Comment: The method of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize` which controls the size of each `UICollectionViewCell`

Comment: Nope. That didn't work either, but I was able to find a workaround. I'll add it as an answer soon for others to see. Thanks for your help!