# Is it possible to define a range constraint for the same layout anchor on iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, uicollectionview, nslayoutconstraint, aspect-ratio

I want to display an image in each cell of `UICollectionView`. The images should have the same width as the screen, but their height will depend on their size. I'd like to make sure the images are constrained to an aspect ratio range (e.g. 1.91 through 4/5). The images stored on the server can be of any aspect ratio; thus, they are not constrained. When shown in a `UICollectionViewCell`, they should aspect scale to fill if they are smaller or larger than the bounding box range (i.e. 1.91 through 4/5).

For example, if an image has 2:1 aspect ratio, it should be clamped to 1.91:1. If it has 1:2 aspect ratio, it should be clamped to 4:5. I'd like to use the new `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`.

[image]

For this effort, originally I thought of pre-computing the heights and storing them in the data model and updating the view heights based on that. See [View height constraints are not set correctly as I scroll UICollectionView up and down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58580490/view-height-constraints-are-not-set-correctly-as-i-scroll-uicollectionview-up-an), but I'm having issues with that approach.

My beginner question is, is it possible to define two constraints for the same anchor to define a range?

```
_imageContainer.heightAnchor.constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToAnchor(_imageContainer.widthAnchor, multiplier: 4.0/5).active = true
_imageContainer.heightAnchor.constraintLessThanOrEqualToAnchor(_imageContainer.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.91).active = true
```

The goal with the above code is to define a range constraint. Does the second constraint override the first one so that the first one is no longer valid? Second, what would the recommended approach be to solve the aforementioned problem with respect to displaying images in different heights?

Answer (score 0):

yes, do as google does in their image API and store the image dimensions in your database.

see their custom search api for route

> customsearch/v1

it returns

```
@"pagemap.cse_thumbnail.width"
@"pagemap.cse_thumbnail.height"
```

once you have those values then in the delgate methods for UICollectionView, specifically `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` you pull out those stored values from the server query and then normalize the size of the cell to the width equalling the total width of the screen with the height adjusting to accommodate.

you'd use a function like this to get the size of the cell in normalized fashion

```
static CGFloat CustomFloatCalc(CGFloat value) {
   CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
   return floor(value * scale) / scale;
}
```

something like so:

```
     CGFloat itemHeight = 0;
     if (itemSize.height > 0 && itemSize.width > 0) {
        itemHeight = CustomFloatCalc(itemSize.height * itemWidth / itemSize.width);
     }
```

now you can calculate the value of the image on the fly on in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` but doing so will ramp up the memory and CPU load on the device. Better to store the values on the backend like Google does.

Good luck

Comment: I believe `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` belongs to the flow layout delegate, but I use `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`. Is `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` still valid in my  case?

Comment: yep, should do the same thing

Comment: Thanks. Just like you suggested, I save the image dimensions in the database. I wasn't able to make constraint changes work. `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` did not work either. However, I found another workaround. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58585722/246392.

Comment: @user246392 Hi , if find the workaround , when have time you can update it in answer and remember to mark it later.